# Is there a declarative way to specify packages to be installed into global-project using Haskell stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Stack allows global installation of packages using `stack install <packagename>` outside of a project directory.

Stack also has a `~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` file that allows configuration of the global-project. However I can't see a way to "install" packages declaratively. The `extra-deps` and `packages` key in the yaml file don't seem to work for this method.

Instead I just have to run `stack install <...> <...>` each time the snapshot version gets updated for my global-project.

Comment: I write this a lot, and here it applies too: **I think the tool you want is Cabal-install, not Stack**. `cabal` installs all packages globally by default. (This used to often lead to conflicts in the past – “Cabal Hell” – which is one reason why Stack became so popular, but thanks to its new [Nix-style versioning](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/) this is not an issue anymore.) Of course, Stack is invaluable to build projects on a clean-slate server / VM and be sure that it'll actually work, but for development, Cabal-install is better IMO.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish here? If the goal is to provide some packages from outside of the snapshot, then using `extra-deps` in the file you referenced works. If you're trying to achieve something else, it would help if you could clarify what's not working.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman When I tried with `extra-deps`, what stack command actualises these packages? I ran with `stack ghci`, but none of the packages listed there were installed. Was there meant to be a specific stack command that will read in all the `extra-deps` and install everything?

Comment: That command doesn't exist, you have to tell Stack _somehow_ which packages you want. For example, you can do `stack ghci --package foobar`. Stack never eagerly installs all available packages. If it did, you'd end up with about 2,500 packages installed, and a possibly melted CPU :)

Comment: In that case, what is the utility of putting my "global" packages into `extra-deps` of `global-project/stack.yaml`? I already run `stack install <...>` for all my global package atm. Note that the only global packages I try to get are the ones that have executables like stylish-haskell, pretty-print, hlint... etc. This is quite useful when these things are not available as packages for the OS/distro you're running (like Windows).

Comment: I'm not sure that it _is_ useful, I've never seen anyone do it before. There are certainly cases you may want it done, but generally I'd recommend some other more reproducible approach (like using the [script interpreter](https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script)). If your goal is to get executables available: I also just use `stack install package-name`.